# How to access table values using xpath in python

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I am trying to access table values which can be found here - https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312515356351/d17062d10k.htm

Specifically, I am trying to access the Net sales figure for 2015 (ie. 233,715) which can be found on page 39 of the 10-K form (see image).

[image].

Here is my code...

```
from lxml import html
import requests

SEC_page = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312515356351/d17062d10k.htm')
SEC_tree = html.fromstring(SEC_page.content)

Description = SEC_tree.xpath('//html/body/document/type/sequence/filename/description/text()')
Sales_2015 = SEC_tree.xpath('//html/body/document/type/sequence/filename/description/text/table[48]/tbody/tr[4]/td[4]/font/text()')

print Description
print Sales_2015
```

We can see that 'Description' prints - ie. ['FORM 10-K\n', '\n']

However, 'Sales_2015' comes back as empty - ie. []

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite hard to debug and find a problem in your expression as you use *absolute `XPath`*. You should avoid using absolute `XPath`. Note that you reffer to `table[48]`! **48, Carl!** You'd better use *relative `XPath`* as it's more flexible, reliable and verbose:

```
(//p[contains(., "CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF OPERATIONS")]/following::td[contains(.,"Net sales")]/following-sibling::td[@align="right"]//text())[1]
```

Here we first found the header of table with text `"CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF OPERATIONS"` then found the following table cell `"Net sales"` and grab the first number in the same row which is `233,715`

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. So what would be the code? Would it be: Sales_2015 = SEC_tree.xpath('//p[.="CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF OPERATIONS"]/following::td[.="Net sales"]/following-sibling::td[@align="right"]//text())[1]')

Comment: Okay - problem solved. You can use absolute xpath if you get rid of the 'tbody' ie - Sales_2015 = SEC_tree.xpath('//html/body/document/type/sequence/filename/description/text/table[48]/tr[4]/td[4]/font/text()'). That returns 233,715

Comment: ...but just out of curiosity, it would be great if you could let me know the correct syntax to arrive at 233,715 using the relative xpath approach... thanks : - )

Comment: There must be some differences in content appearence for different user-agents... Try this `SEC_tree.xpath('(//p[contains(., "CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF OPERATIONS")]/following::td[contains(.,"Net sales")]/following-sibling::td[@align="right"]//text())[1]')`. It should work. And yes, you shouldn't use `tbody` tag in `XPath` as it might not be present in initial page source, but added dinamically by browser

Comment: Hey - that's great! Thanks